# powerOnIcc() works for one chip card but not for another

Tags: android, sdk, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I am trying to establish communication between chip card reader and chip card. I have two types of chip card. One is a visa card and another is prepaid meter card.

The documentation of card reader states that I need to invoke pos.powerOnIcc() first before sending APDU commands. I did so for both types of card. The response from visa card was a successful one but the prepaid meter card returned a null response.

Note that, the card reader was able to detect the prepaid card through pos.isCardExist() and I was able to read that prepaid card from another card reader.

This is high level overview of my problem and I am particularly interested in difference between visa card and prepaid chip card in this case.

I am using this sdk: https://gitlab.com/dspread/android

I am using this sdk: https://gitlab.com/dspread/android

Comment: I'm not convinced, that the meter card communicates via a standard/protocol, which the problematic reader supports. Try to find out, what type of card it is, e.g. via Android NFC tag apps.

Comment: It is a SLE4428 card.

Comment: SLE4428 is a memory card. You may find some answers  searching for that type here. Its not really astonishing, that such an old card with little protection possibilities is not supported by a modern reader. To identify an appropriate reader search for support of 2-wire and 3-wire protocol.

Comment: Yep, that method seems to ask for an ATR, which is a problem if the card doesn't do ATR's as expected. Looking a bit on the interweb shows that you may need specific reader & library support. I found a few on .. Alibaba .. uh and mention of support by Gemplus. And yeah, Gemplus -> Gemalto -> Thales... Different world.